# solve recurrence relation: comparisons to construct binary search tree with maple

Tags: recurrence-relations, trees, maple

I would like to solve the recurrence relation for the average number of comparisons necessary to the construction of a binary search tree.

the recurrence is 
$$
i(n) = n - 1 + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}i(k), \quad i(0) = 0
$$

and the result of `rsolve` is:

```
rsolve({i(0) = 0, i(n) = n-1+2*(sum(i(k), k = 0 .. n-1))/n}, i(n))
```

(It does nothing)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you asking about debugging the Maple code?  What do you expect or want the code to do, solve the recurrence relation for $i(n)$ as a function of $n$ explicitly?

Comment: He seems to mean [this command](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=rsolve).

Comment: Looking at the examples I wonder if your second argument should be `rsolve({..}, i}` or `rsolve({..}, {i}}`. Also your equation uses the summation  function, maybe try it without that part first, in case Maple can not cope with such function specifications.

Comment: @hardmath i would like to obtain the generating function of the recurrence  or at least evaluate it on some points

Comment: @mvw the arguments should be correct, if i try applying rsolve to the recurrence without the summation maple works.

Comment: @DuccioBertieri I was able to reformulate the recurrence without sum. That might be digestible by `rsolve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the solver is not able to handle the summation statement.
Trying now to avoid the summation:
\begin{align}
i(n) &= n - 1 + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}i(k) \\
i(n+1) &= n + \frac{2}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^ni(k) \\
&= \frac{2}{n+1}i(n) + n + \frac{2}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} i(k) \\
&= \frac{2}{n+1}i(n) + n + \frac{n}{n+1} 
\left( i(n) - n + 1 \right) \\
&= \frac{n+2}{n+1} i(n)-\frac{n^2}{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+1} + n \\
&= \frac{n+2}{n+1} i(n) + \frac{2n}{n+1} \\
\end{align}
This gives: 
$$
i(n) = \frac{n+1}{n} i(n-1) - \frac{2}{n} + 2 \quad (n > 0)
$$
which you should be able to feed to Maple.

**Test:** The first sequence elements are
\begin{align}
i(0) &= 0 \\
i(1) &= 0 \\
i(2) &= 1 \\
i(3) &= 2 + 2/3 = 8/3 \\
i(4) &= 3 + 11/6 = 29 / 6 =^! 5/4 \, 8/3 - 1/2 + 2 = 10/3 + 3/2 = 29/6 
\end{align}

Comment: Your first part is very similar to the sequence of steps I did (but all done using Maple, and not shown explicitly) to obtain the arguments I passed to rsolve in my answer. But I passed it an equation with `it(n+1)` and `it(n)` whereas you subsequently decremented the index to get a final equation with `i(n)` and `i(n-1)`. The result from `rsolve` for term `i(n)` is the same, however. And it generates the same values.

Comment: I saw the relation afterwards, it was harder to see in the preformatted code. My goal was to show that if a summation is part of $i(n)$ then the summation for $i(n+1)$ is only one term more, so that one can try to express the sum in terms of $i(n)$ as well, so that we end up just with $i(n+1)$ in terms of $i(n)$ or index shifted $i(n)$ in terms of $i(n-1)$ and not the other earlier $i(k)$ values.

Comment: I quite agree (and vote up). Perhaps I ought to have also shown my programmatic steps which did that (using summation calls).

Answer (score 3):

Would you be ok with an answer like,

```
i(n) = (2*n+2)*Psi(n+1)+(2*gamma-4)*n+2*gamma;
```

where Psi is the digamma function as defined [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Psi)?

I got that by issuing following in Maple 2015,

```
rsolve( {(it(n+1) - n/(n+1)*it(n) - n + n^2/(n+1)
          - n/(n+1))*(n+1)/2 = it(n), it(0)=0}, it(n) );
```

Comment: (+1). This looks impressive. It just needs converting the Psi function into a harmonic number so the asymptotics are more apparent.

Comment: sorry but this is too difficult for me :(..
i have not done yet the gamma function, and i have not understood how do you reach the solution..